# Find line, then get the next line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following problem:
I open a file and read it line by line searching for a specific pattern. When I found it, I would like to write the entire line AND THE NEXT TWO LINES into a new file. The problem is that I don't know how to get from the line that I've found to the next 2.

```
AAA
XXX
XXX
BBB
XXX
XXX
CCC
XXX
XXX
```

In this example it would be that I find "BBB" and I want to get the next two lines.

What could I do? Thank you very much for your kind help!

Edit: I realized that I have to ask more precisely.

This is the code from my colleague

```
for k in range(0,len(watcrd)):
    if cvt[k]>cvmin:
        intwat+=1
        sumcv+=cvt[k]
        sumtrj+=trj[k]/((i+1)*sep/100)
        endline='%5.2f %5.2f' % (cvt[k],trj[k]/((i+1)*sep/100)) # ivan
        ftrj.write(watline[k][:55]+endline+'\n')
        fall.write(watline[k][:55]+endline+'\n')
```

For every `k in range` I would like to write `k, k+1, k+2` to the file ftrj.
Which is the best way to do this?

Edit 2: I am sorry, but I realized that I've made a mistake. What you suggested worked, but I realized that I have to include it in a different part of the code.

```
for line in lines[model[i]:model[i+1]]:
    if line.startswith('ATOM'):
    resi=line[22:26]
    resn=line[17:20]
    atn=line[12:16]
    crd=[float(line[31:38]),float(line[38:46]),float(line[46:54])]

    if (resn in noprot)==False and atn.strip().startswith('CA')==True:
        protcrd.append(crd)
    if (resn in reswat)==True and (atn.strip() in atwat)==True:
        watcrd.append(crd)
        watline.append(line)
```

I would think of something like this:

```
    (...)
    if (resn in reswat)==True and (atn.strip() in atwat)==True:
        watcrd.append(crd)
        watline.append(line)
        for i in range(1, 3):
            try:
                watcrd.append(crd[line + i])
                watline.append(line[line + i])
            except IndexError:
                break
```

But it doesn't work. How can I indicate the part and the line that I want to append to this list?

Answer (score 5):

Python file objects are iterators, you can always ask for the next lines:

```
with open(inputfilename) as infh:
    for line in infh:
        if line.strip() == 'BBB':
            # Get next to lines:
            print next(infh)
            print next(infh)
```

Here [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) advances the `infh` iterator to the next line, returning that line.

However, you are not processing a file; you are processing a list instead; you can always access later indices in the list:

```
    ftrj.write(watline[k][:55]+endline+'\n')
    fall.write(watline[k][:55]+endline+'\n')
    for i in range(1, 3):
        try:
            ftrj.write(watline[k + i][:55]+endline+'\n')
            fall.write(watline[k + i][:55]+endline+'\n')
        except IndexError:
            # we ran out of lines in watline
            break
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this considered more "pythonic" than finding the index and and getting ```lines[index:index+2]```?

Comment: You don't have an index when you're iterating over the file.

Comment: @wnnmaw: this reads the file line by line (using buffered I/O) without needing to read the whole file into memory at once. That is much more efficient than reading the whole file into a list then manipulating the list.

Comment: @njzk2: but an iterator is not indexable; you can have your count but not use it to access other lines at will.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I know, I was just reacting to Matthias comment. You'd have an index, yet completely useless.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I think I have posed my question not precisely enough.

I have some code from a colleague and he opened it as `for in in range(...)` Would it then be `print next(range(...))`?

And furthermore I want to append this to a list. So should it be `lst.append(next(range(..))`

Comment: @Julian: No, you'll have to post the code your colleague wrote. A `range()` object produces a new iterable object producing only indices, which probably means there is a separate list of lines.